SPL-TOKEN mint --disable not working
while trying to set max supply by disabling the mint i got an error
spl-token authorize mntZFtv8SvH6trqeSwvXXXXXXXXXXX mint --disable

Updating mntZFtv8SvH6trqeSwvXXXXXXXXXXX
  Current mint: B5PdLiFsLR7c8r6pwmLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  New mint: disabled
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x4", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, Custom(4))), logs: Some(["Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]", "Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority", "Program log: Error: owner does not match", "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 1364 of 1364 compute units", "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: custom program error: 0x4"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(1364), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) })


The error code 0x4 in the token program corresponds to OwnerMismatch, which means that you're not signing with the current mint authority.
If you're using the CLI, you'll need to specify the current mint authority with the --authority flag, ie:
spl-token authorize --authority <KEYPAIR> mint <MINT> --disable


I think this may be because you are using the SPL-Token Program rather than Token-2022.
Try adding -p TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb to your command since the error suggests your token is SPL-2022.
Otherwise, I'd guess that your CLI is not configed to the current authority. You can fix that by doing solana config set -k <Path_to_auth>
Source: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d2f5144c1650179376cb0e2fad6aa656ffd5749a/token/program/src/processor.rs#L425
